# Count with GroupBy Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below are 2 tables-

```
JOBS
JobID ProcessID Status
j1    p1          Start 
j2    p2          Stop
j3    p2          Running
j4    p1          Start
j4    p1          Stop
```

Table 2

```
PROCESSES
ProcessID  Name    ProcessGroup
P1         P1Name   G1
P2         P2Name   G2
P3         P3Name   G1
```

Expected outcome-

```
Process StartCount  StopCount
P1Name      2           1
P2Name      0           1
```

I am trying to use group by query for above output.

```
select jobId,p.Name, COUNT(j.j.JobID) as StartCount
from JOBS j,
PROCESSES p
where j.Status = 'Start' and
      j.ProcessID= p.ProcessID
group by j.Status
```

In a single query, I can get a count of only Start or StopCount. Can I get both in a single query?

Comment: What is your RDBMS, Oracle or SQL Server? If SQL Server then 2005, 2008 or 2012+?

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Answer (score 5):

You can use *conditional aggregation* for this:

```
select p.Name, 
       count(case when Status = 'Start' then 1 end) as StartCount,
       count(case when Status = 'Stop' then 1 end) as StopCount
from JOBS j
join PROCESSES p on j.ProcessID = p.ProcessID      
group by p.Name
```

Comment: Thank you for re-working the query to include an explicit `JOIN` rather than the 25 year old implicit syntax!